# Command to list all files except . (dot) and .. (dot dot)

Tags: linux, shell, ls

I'm trying to find a command that would list all files (including hidden files), but must exclude the current directory and parent directory. Please help.

```bash
$ ls -a \.\..
```

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Regarding the [ls(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html) documentation (`man ls`):

> -A, --almost-all           do not list implied . and ..

you need (*without* any additional argument such as `.*`):

```
ls -A
```

or better yet:

```
/bin/ls -A
```

Comment: How come `/bin/ls -A` excludes the dot directories, but `ls -A` does not? At least, that is the case on my system, which runs a distro based on Ubuntu 14.04.5.

Comment: @AndyForceno: probably `ls` is some alias (or shell function) e.g. in your `.bashrc`

Comment: `\ls -A` to disable ls alias, but /bin/ls is bullet proof :)

Answer (score 6):

```
$ ls -lA
```

works best for my needs.

For convenience I recommend to define an alias within .bashrc-file as follows:

```
alias ll='ls -lA'
```

Answer (score 4):

I have a situation where I want to remove a series of dot-directories. In my servers we mark directories for removal adding a dot and certain other text patterns (timestamp) for automated removal. Sometimes I need to do that manually.

As I commented to [Basile Starynkevitch's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/841108/basile-starynkevitch) reply, when you use a globbing pattern like the one below the -A switch loses its function and works just as -a:

```
 runlevel0@ubuntu:~/scripts$ ls -1dA .*
.
..
.comparepp.sh.swp
```

It would most certainly give an error if I try to remove files as a user, but I just don't want to think what could happen as root (!)

My approach in this case is:

```
for dir in $(ls -1ad .* | tail -n +3) ; do rm -rfv $dir  ; done
```

I tail out the 2 first line containing the dots as you can see. To tailor the answer to the question asked this would do the job:

```
ls -d1A .* | tail -n +3
```

Comment: BTW, as root nothing happens except an error message "cannot remove" but still, better to be over-cautious with production servers.